# how do you include other packages when creating a new package in RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to build a custom package for myself using RStudio. I need to inlude other available packages in my env.

In NAMESPACE file, I put:

```
export(forecast)
export(jsonlite)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: forecast, jsonlite
```

How do you include/reference other packages in your package in RStudio?

Comment: That should be `import()`.  `export()` is for making your functions available to other packages.

Comment: @RichardScriven, I have one more question, when I build this packages I have bunch files in a directory. How do I install this packages to my linux? Do I zip all this files into one, and do package install from source?

Comment: You need to check and build the tarball.  It's all [in here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-and-building-packages)